# Alternative to $_GET["param"] to keep %0A line breaks?

Tags: php, get

I am sending info from an HTML form through the URL to be used at the destination web page.

One of these bits of info is a user defined message from a `textarea`, potentially with line breaks. I've encoded the linebreaks as `%0A`.

I wanted to use `$var = $_GET["param"]` to retrieve the message and store in a variable, but of course `$_GET` strips the `%0A` and replaces with spaces, which is killing the user formatting.

Is there someway I can get this into the variable either with the `%0A` in tact, or converted to `<br>`'s.

Thanks for you help.

---

**UPDATE: Here's the code**

Example URL:

`http://blahblahblah.com/thankyou.php?type=e&gift=1&remail=simon@shokstudio.com&rname=Simon&demail=simon@shokstudio.com&dname=Simon&msg=e.g.%20Dear%20Bob,%20%0A%0AMerry%20Christmas%20and%20a%20Happy%20New%20Year%20to%20you.%20I%20hope%202014%20brings%20you%20much%20joy%20and%20happiness%20to%20you%20and%20your%20loved%20ones.%0A%0ABest%20Wishes,%0A%0ADave%0A%0A%20`

PHP processing URL:

```
         <?php

            if ( "e" == $_GET["type"]) :
                $gift_type = "Ecard";
            else :
                $gift_type = "PDF";
            endif;

            $gift_number = $_GET['gift'];

            $donor_name = $_POST['dname'];
            $donor_email = $_GET['demail'];

            $recipient_name = $_POST['rname'];
            $recipient_email = $_GET['remail'];

            $custom_text = $_POST['msg'];

            echo $_POST['msg'];
```

Comment: Check whether your URL contain space or special characters

Comment: URL contains spaces and line breaks encoded as %20 and %0A respectively.

Comment: I've tried $_POST["param"], but nothing is being stored (or echoed).

Comment: K, have updated question with code

Comment: You should be sending everything with `POST`. So replace all occurrences of `$_GET` with `$_POST`. Then on your form replace `method="GET"` to `method="POST"`. Your action parameter on the form is then simply thankyou.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` instead of `GET`. This works fine.

**form.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="my_form.php">
    <input type="text" name="param">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**my_form.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['param'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Your solution is right. The issue for me was that the data was coming back from a PayPal return URL and not as POST method.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) or [str-replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/function.preg-replace). But to use `POST` instead of `GET` that would be a better and safe solution solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a web-form with a text-area, i would suggest using the POST method and then using the $_POST (or $_REQUEST) variable instead. All entered data should be in there, with enters and all special characters.

Comment: Aren't $_REQUEST variables passed through urldecode as well? Let me try $_POST